# How do I know which TouchableNativeFeedback I pressed?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to press on a row in the FlatList and make the app navigate to another page, and I'm trying to do this without creating new methods for each render.

Using React I would just get the value from `event.target` but I'm having trouble doing this in react native

Here's what I have so far:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this._renderListItem = ({ item }) => this.renderListItem(item)

    this._onPressListItem = () => this.onPressListItem()
}

onPressListItem() {
    // Right here I need to know which row I pressed
    this.props.navigation.navigate('ChatScreen', {})
}

renderListItem(item) {
    return (
        <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={this._onPressListItem}>
            <View style={{ height: 50, backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
                <Text>{item.name}</Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableNativeFeedback>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In render part you just need to define the item when press TouchableNativeFeedback like this

```
renderListItem(item) {
return (
    <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={()=>{this._onPressListItem(item)}}>
        <View style={{ height: 50, backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
            <Text>{item.name}</Text>
        </View>
    </TouchableNativeFeedback>
)
}
```

And then you can find out which particular row as been clicked

```
onPressListItem(items) {
console.log(items)
}
```

In console you will get the value for that par item pressed in the row 
try may be this can help you

Comment: Thank you for the response, but the problem I see with this solution is that every time a new ListItem is created `onPress` creates a new function just for that bind, im trying to avoid that.

Comment: you can use map in that you only need to pass the items array and then it will work as same it working right now .